# How to determine if someone is typing on editText

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

I am designing a chat application using android studio and i am using fire-base as cloud service provider and i got stock on how to make a listener like if the user is typing on the edit-text field The value of the user on fire-base will changed into true and when the user is not typing the value will become false.? I am looking for this solution for about a week, and didn't find any answer regarding on my researches.

How to put TextWatcher?

EDIT

```
       final Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://my-first-sample-is.firebaseio.com/");


            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(this, Message.class, R.layout.fragment_message, firebase.child("chat")));
            editText.setAdapter(new RoomTypeAdapter(this, RoomType.class, R.layout.fragment_message1, firebase.child("Room-Typing")));

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
  Message message = new Message();

                message.setMessage(editText.getText().toString());
                editText.setText("");
                message.setAuthor("Name");
                message.setNumMessages(numMessages);


                firebase.child("chat").push().setValue(message);


            }
        });
        editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please search the last line of your question in Google.

Comment: Please show your effort, the solutions to this question are everywhere

Comment: Too old question .Use `Text Watcher`

Comment: even if it will show the changes in firebase? ,

Comment: sorry thats why am asking. i tried to implement textwatcher , but the nothing happens on the firebase everytime i type on the textfield ,

Comment: yeah this is duplicate . i just need to know , because i tried it many times using textwatcher ,

Comment: @jaymeesantosan Hi, If you already knew its a duplicate, then you shouldn't be posting this question. You have to tell us exactly what is the issue. (the specific problem. _nothing happens on the firebase everytime i type on the textfield_ this is not specific, and we can't help it.)

Comment: sorry guis.my problem  here is that the  textwatcher doesn't change its attribute in to true everytime i type on the editext , .

Comment: i do have a data structure in firebase for room-type , so there.you will know whos user is typing.

Comment: If you tried to implement `TextWatcher` please show us some relevant codes. and tell us what is the output you got and what was the expected result.

Comment: I see you have already asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794898/how-to-make-a-listener-when-a-user-start-typing

Comment: i now edit , and show the code , it's now updated , look guis,

Comment: yes boss, my apology

Answer (score 6):

Implement the TextWatcher on your edittext like this

```
    EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
  myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) {
   // Here you can trigger your another code/function about which you are asking
   }
  });
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use OnFocusChangeListener, if the textview has focus then the user is typing. for more information you can check here 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html