# In Chat App How to implement Typing indicator using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In chat App how to implement Typing indicator that someone is Typing just like whats-app or Messenger in Android Studio using Firebase

[image: as shown in the Figure]

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797431/how-to-determine-if-someone-is-typing-on-edittext

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this, you need add a new field in your Firebase database named: `typing` with the default value of `false`. Then use `addTextChangedListener()` method on your `EditText` to actually see when someone types a message. When someone types something, `onTextChanged()` method is triggered. Now change the value of `typing` from false to `true`. After this, `addValueEventListener` to see when the value is changed. If the value is true, then display that message in your chat room. So, i suggest you using the following code:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            //Set the value of typing field to true.
        } else {
            // Set to false
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

Comment: I need one more help how to update isTyping in database when someOne is Typing my database hierarchy as shown:    https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/websolutionseo-8c349.appspot.com/o/Capture.PNG?alt=media&token=3f78dfc5-ec33-40d1-af19-e0853d0f2b5c

Comment: Will you  please provide me a piece of code to understand this.How to implement typing features in android

Comment: If the typing field was true during the writing and the user left the app and failed to connect with Firestore to update it to false what will happen, What is the best practice to avoid this scenario?

Comment: @muco2 You might also consider reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/app-start-foreground-background-traces?platform=android).