# How to show typing indicator in android firebase chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-edittext

I need to implement typing indicator in chat application using firebase.
I have a logic like

- Add a textwatcher listener and  in text change listener update flag of a field named typing in firebase db
- Then i think when a value change it will notify the value change listener

  if any one has a code implementation please share.

[image]

Comment: can you show us what you have tried with the code ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén i have done only chating part , i stucked at this part no code implemented

Comment: Your logic seems pretty fair. It will work, go for it.

Comment: Post your firebase data structure

Comment: @JinsLukose Here I found same question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915206/1318946

Comment: @PratikButani i have no use for that

Comment: @ManojPerumarath i know the logic but i need a working implementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check code below: `

make structure something like: (it may vary as per your need I am just referring something to you)

[image]

> I have an object **"isTyping"** with Two Keys Let's say **"first_user"** and **"second_user".** 
>   If you want to check for **"second_user"** is typing or not this should be the code.

```
  private void checkForOtherUserTypingStatus() {
        mMessageThread.child("isTyping").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("second_user") && dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("true")) {
                    updateTypingViewVisibility(true);
                } else if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("second_user") && dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("false")) {
                    updateTypingViewVisibility(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("second_user") && dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("true")) {
                        updateTypingViewVisibility(true);
                    } else if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("second_user") && dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("false")) {
                        updateTypingViewVisibility(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

> To update value of **"isTyping" > "first_user"** (assume that you are typing)

```
 mBinder.etChatMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("first_user", charSequence.length() > 0);
                mMessageThread.child("isTyping").updateChildren(params);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: let me check and let you know

Comment: Yeah Sure! I had nearly same functionality and implemented this

Comment: where this idTyping parameter should be placed

Comment: in your messageThread parent. so that within that thread, you can track both the users' typing status

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: i mean in firebase table check my table in the update

Comment: I just created a sample chat thread to show you how it will work, please check attached image and mentioned code, you will have a better idea

Comment: i think your db structure make sense .thanks for every thing i will inform by tommorow

Comment: Welcome Mate!!! Happy Coding

Comment: @JinsLukose : did it work for you?

Comment: excellent solution

Comment: Thanks Mate!!! Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

Yes . you got it right. in user node maintain one boolean flag like `isTyping`.

on `textwatcherListener` change the value to true and yeah `onValueChangeListner` will also trigger so that you can set `Typing` on recipients screen by getting that boolean Value

Comment: did you have any code implementation?

Comment: @JinsLukose  no . i'm just representing a logic . that's how you can implement .

Comment: ok thanks for the response

Comment: @JinsLukose  i hope your doubt is cleared now

Comment: Actually i am looking for a code implementation

Comment: @JinsLukose : please check my answer

Comment: @JinsLukose its not that difficult  just get edittext value change listener and inside it update your firebase . post your existing code otherwise

Comment: But how can detect if the user terminates the application during typing how do we manage ?

Comment: @SathishGadde you can add `isTyping` false inside `onDestroy` method of activity.

Comment: @TejasPandya that's ok, but if user disable internet and exit from the app how do we manage ?

Comment: Good point @TejasPandya, that one also not manageable.